# Nested form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm putting together a form to create an order, where one order has many order items. I have it working so it lists all the available products with blank quantity fields, and the user can update those fields to order large amounts of each product.

I validate the numericality of the quantities in the order item model.

The only issue now though is how I show the errors from the order item model if the user enters invalid data? Currently I can only get 'order item is invalid'..

You can see my form here, I'm using haml and formtastic:
http://gist.github.com/513023

Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to customize the error message?

Comment: Not really, I'd like it to show the specific error from the order item model 'quantity should be a number' rather than only 'order item is invalid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used Formtastic myself, but have you got:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_item
```

...in your order model?

Comment: Hey Scott, 

I'd seen that phrase about with reference to the semantic_fields_for option in formtastic, but hadn't understood it would also work for my slightly different implementation .. But it worked perfectly!

Thanks very much!